# ¿Se puede hacer un programa para MacOs en Python?

Tags: python

antes que nada me gustaría aclarar que soy nuevo en esto de la programación, pero me gusta mucho. Para un proyecto tengo que desarrollar un programa para Mac, ahorita estoy aprendiendo Python, pero no sé si se pueda correr un programa hecho en Python en una Mac, sé que la plataforma de para iOs y MacOs es Xcode, pero tal vez sea posible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

claro que puedes ejecutar código Python en un sistema MacOS, ya que este es multiplataforma, xcode es un ide para desarrollar aplicaciones, quizá si detallar aplicaciones.